# Change background color over date on cell

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

i have a google spreadsheet document where every time you type it sets a timestamp on the cell next to it, I need for that document to change the background color after 3 days of the date on the timestamp cell, do you guys know any script or a way to setup a conditional formatting?..

Im using google spreadsheet

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are in ColumnA, please try selecting ColumnA, Format > Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is**:

```
=and(A1<>"",A1<today()-2)
```

choose your formatting and <kbd>Save rules</kbd>.